# passing Jan of selected year by default in prompt

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-10

I have 2 year-month prompts. If I don't select any year-month in 1st prompt, report should by default, run from January of the same year, selected in 2nd prompt. My prompts are value prompts and have string values. Please help me materialise the requirement. I have already tried # prompt macro, ?prompt?, case when etc. I am nto sure, If javascript would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your underlying date fields are not stored as DATE value types since you're using strings. This may be easier split into 4 prompts: from month, from year, to month, to year.

The filter would then be an implied if:

```
(
(?FROM_YEAR? = '' or ?FROM_MONTH? = '')  and 
[database_from_month] = '01' and
[database_from_year] = ?TO_YEAR? and
[database_to_month] = ?TO_MONTH? and
[database_to_year] = ?TO_YEAR? 
)
OR
(
(?FROM_YEAR? <> '' or ?FROM_MONTH? <> '')  and 
[database_from_month] = ?FROM_MONTH? and
[database_from_year] = ?FROM_YEAR? and
[database_to_month] = ?TO_MONTH? and
[database_to_year] = ?TO_YEAR? 
)
```

The above style filter is superior for many reasons:

- More likely to be sargeable
- Easy to understand
- Uses simple built-in Cognos functions; more likely to be cross-version compliant
- No issues with cross-browser support you would get with Javascript
- Code snippet would work in other Cognos studios (Business Insight, etc)

You've likely seen CASE statements in filters throws an error. The CASE statement is passed to SQL, not compiled into a SQL statement via Cognos. Hence it's not seen as proper syntax.

Comment: ,your solution looks very good. But, since we have to maintain consistency across reports, we have to provide date prompts in YYYY-MM format (in string format which is in the time dimension). I would still try to accomodate my situation using your code. Thanks so much.

Comment: It is possible to use a single prompt for FROM and TO, it was just easier to explain that way. Just parse it out. If this helps, please accept answer and upvote.

Comment: Consider setting up a calendar table, with a 'FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR' field at the YEAR level, a 'YYYY-MM' field at the month level.